# Change background colour of {verbatim} environment

Tags: verbatim, preamble

In an existing document which is not to be modified (except for the preamble), all instances of `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` should have their contents rendered not only in a monospaced font but also on a grey background.

How can this be done?

Comment: Would this suffice: [verbatim with black background and white text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9033/10898)?

Comment: @azetina no, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\let\oldv\verbatim
\let\oldendv\endverbatim

\def\verbatim{\par\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\oldv}
\def\endverbatim{\oldendv\egroup\fboxsep0pt \noindent\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{\usebox0}\par}

\begin{document}

text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
\begin{verbatim}
1
12
123\foo{\ $ &
}
\end{verbatim}
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: However this prevents page breaks. Maybe an approach with `mdframed`?

Comment: @egreg true, I meant to mention that. This question just got asked with a nice looking answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/background-color-in-verbatim